# Beginner trouble do...while loop

Tags: java, console, while-loop, do-while

I am extremely new to Java but have a "little" experience with VB.NET, which is much more forgiving. So please forgive what is likely a silly question and also forgive my poor java vocabulary.
Here is a snippet of the console application:

```
do
{
    out.println("Please enter the name of your space bug and press <enter> to continue");
    out.println();
    bugOne.setName(keyInput.nextLine());

    out.println("You have entered '" + bugOne.getName() + "'.");
    out.println("Is this correct? (y/n)");

    confirmName = keyInput.findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0);
}
while(confirmName != 'y' && confirmName != 'Y');
```

On the first iteration it is fine and the name entered shows up. Then it moves onto the confirmation, where if I key in 'y' or 'Y' it drops into the next line of code fine (as you would expect).

But if I key in anything else, when it goes through the second iteration it doesn't pause for keyboard input. After I hit enter to the confirmName request the lines produced in the console window immediately read

```
You have entered "".
Is this correct(y/n)?
```

Why is it not pausing for keyboard input? (In a VB console app you have to specify when you want to pause for user input but from what I have seen in Java you don't or can't... or CAN you?)

And why is my 'name' variable which is set through the accessor method setName being assigned a value of nothing automatically on the second iteration??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you do

```
confirmName = keyInput.findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0);
```

You're using a pattern (`.`) to tell the scanner to find the very next character. However, once the user enters a response, there's more than one character (i.e. there's 'n' as well as a newline character). But findWithinHorizon doesn't pick up that newline character, so when it comes back around to

```
bugOne.setName(keyInput.nextLine());
```

It's immediately picking up that empty new line that was left in there. To fix this, you can just put the following line of code right after your call to findWithinHorizon:

```
keyInput.nextLine();
```

So it'll look like this:

```
confirmName = keyInput.findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0);
keyInput.nextLine();
```

But really, what's the harm in doing something like this? Forget about the pattern matching and just read it in as a string.

```
String confirmName;
do
{
    out.println("Please enter the name of your space bug and press <enter> to continue");
    out.println();
    bugOne.setName(keyInput.nextLine());

    out.println("You have entered '" + bugOne.getName() + "'.");
    out.println("Is this correct? (y/n)");

    confirmName = keyInput.nextLine();
}
while(!confirmName.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. That makes sense. Honestly, I don't know why I was using a char type instead of a string for the confirmName variable, it was just something I read somewhere I think. If I was using VB I would have been using a string compare or something similar. Sorry if this is a dumb question but what is the "!" in while(!confirmName.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) and can I pass in multiple values to equalsIgnoreCase so that it handles upper and lower case or do I need to use a .ToLower with the nextLine() method? Can a ToLower be tacked onto the end of that method?

Comment: @user2774915 `confirmName.equalsIgnoreCase("y")` returns whether `confirmName` is equal to "y" or "Y", and like the method name implies, it doesn't care whether the two strings are upper or lower. On the other hand, `confirmName.equals("y")` returns true only if the user enters a lowercase "y". `!` (read: not) is the negation operator, much like you do `a != b` (or in VB `a <> b`), the `!` reverses the boolean value, so the entire expression evaluates to true only if what the user entered is not equal to "Y" or "y". Yes, you could do `!confirmName.toLower().equals("y")`, but there's no need.

Comment: Thank you very much. I assumed that was what the ! was for but just wanted to be sure. Can the equals method accept multiple values though? Say in another situation could I have a !confirmWhatever.equalsIgnoreCase("red" || "blue")

Comment: @user2774915 No, it only takes [one string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29), so you'd have to do `!(confirmWhatever.equalsIgnoreCase("red") || confirmWhatever.equalsIgnoreCase("blue"))`

Answer (score 1):

To read a character/string from console, you could do the below (taken from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-input-from-console-java/)):

```
try{
        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = bufferRead.readLine();

        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Also the string can not be compared with `==` and `!=` operators; use String's `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`.

See here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equalsignorecase.htm

Comment: I guess I should mention that keyInput is an instance of a scanner(in). But people could probably know that by seeing the call to nextLine().